# Getting "function is not defined" error when trying to use a function in useEffect and on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to create a click handler function that calls the `laodData` function to refire, so I can get a new Dad joke, but I'm getting this error:

> The error says loadData is not defined.

```
function App() {
  //data storage
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState([]);
  const API_LINK = "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/";

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`${API_LINK}`, { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } });
      console.log(response.data.joke);
      setJoke(response.data.joke);
    };
    loadData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2 className="title">The Absolute Best Dad jokes.</h2>
      <div className="joke">{joke}</div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={loadData}>
        Get Another Joke
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created `loadData` in `useEffect`'s callback, so you can only acces it within its scope. As you can read on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope):

> A function creates a scope, so that (for example) a variable defined exclusively within the function cannot be accessed from outside the function or within other functions.

You should move `loadData` outside of the `useEffect` to be able to call it on click as well, like so:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
function App() {
  //data storage
  const [joke, setJoke] = useState("");
  const API_LINK = "https://icanhazdadjoke.com/";

  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${API_LINK}`, { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } });
    console.log(response.data.joke);
    setJoke(response.data.joke);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2 className="title">The Absolute Best Dad jokes.</h2>
      <div className="joke">{joke}</div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={loadData}>
        Get Another Joke
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

[image]